# Calling scanf() after another string input function creates phantom input

Tags: c, scanf

Here's a small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char str[21], choice[21]; int size;
  while(1){
    printf("$ ");
    fgets(str, 20, stdin);
    printf("Entered string: %s", str);
    if(str[0] == 'q') {
      printf("You sure? (y/n) ");
      scanf("%s", choice);
      if(choice[0] == 'y' || choice[0] == 'Y')
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It reads a string using `fgets()`. If the string starts with a `q`, it confirms if the user wants to quit, and exits if the user types `y`.

When I run it and type `q`, this happens:

```
$ q
Entered string: q
You sure? (y/n) n
$ Entered string: 
$
```

Note the `$ Entered string:`. Clearly, `fgets()` got an empty character or something as input, even though I didn't type anything.

What's going on?

Comment: better to use `int` for `choice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in other answer `scanf` call leaves the newline  in the input buffer you can also use `getchar()` after scanf like this :

```
scanf("%20s", choice);// always remember( & good) to include field width 
                      // in scanf while reading
```

Strings otherwise it will overwrite buffer in case of large strings `

```
getchar();  //this will eat up the newline
```

Besides , you should also use fgets like this :

```
fgets(str,sizeof str, stdin); //Its better
```

Comment: Check: [Help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17615082/revisions) instead of ``` use `ctr + K` for code part.

Answer (score 2):

It because the `scanf` call reads a character, but leaves the newline in the buffer. So when you next time call `fgets` is finds that one newline character and reads it resulting in an empty line being read.

The solution is deceptively simple: Put a space after the format in the `scanf` call:

```
scanf("%s ", choice);
/*       ^    */
/*       |    */
/* Note space */
```

This will cause `scanf` to read and discard all training whitespace, including newlines.

Comment: That can't happen for input `q`. fgets() would read the newline as well.

Comment: @KingsIndian Yes, but the question is about the case when the programs continues after the `scanf` call, which *does* leave the newline.

Comment: The explanation sounds right (why didn't I notice the newline? *facepalm*), but the solution doesn't work. After I add that space, the `scanf()` call doesn't terminate. I tried adding using `"%s\n"` too, but that doesn't terminate either.

Comment: OP's question and example specifically talk about input `q`. I think the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @Anubhav Since you are are only interested in a single character, why not scan for a single character? Try e.g. `scanf("%c ", &char_choice);`. Might work better.

Comment: @KingsIndian Yes, the question mentions `q`, but it's what happens *after* the the `q` is read that is the problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Using a char has the same problem. `scanf` doesn't terminate if I add the space, and leaves a newline in the buffer if I don't.

Comment: Right. I see the mix up now. Ironically Anubhav claims this still doesn't fix the issue. That's strange.

Comment: @Anubhav That is *really* weird. It shouldn't do that in either case.

Comment: Using `getchar()` does work, though. (See other answer.) Maybe the extra character is something other than `\n`? EDIT: Nope, printing out the ASCII value shows that it's '\n' (ASCII 10).

Comment: The space in the `scanf` format consumes all whitespace after the "%s" conversion succeeded. So `scanf` doesn't return before it encounters the next non-whitespace character, @Anubhav.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'char' of a specific size `char choice [1]`

OR

```
char c[1];
c = getchar();
if(c[0] == 'y' || c[1] == 'y'){
 // DO SOMETHING
}
```