# My program skip getting input data?

Tags: c, scanf

I have written a simple program to exchange currency and able to buy a beer.

But there something in program and I don't know why, it auto skips the third input data -> end program.

Here my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ex_rate_into_vnd = 20000; //! Exchange Rate
    int beer = 7000; //! Local price of a beer
    float in_c = 0; //! Input amount of money
    float out_c = 2; //! Amount of currency to exchange !
    float choice; //! Switch mode
    char buy; //! Deal or not

    //! Introduction
    printf ("||---------------------------------------------------||\n");
    printf ("||         Currency Exchange Machine  beta           ||\n");
    printf ("||---------------------------------------------------||\n");

    printf ("Please choose your option:\n");
    printf("\t 1.Exchange VND to dollar\n");
    printf("\t 2.Exchange Dollar to VND\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Your choice: ",choice);
        scanf("%f",&choice);
    } while( choice != 1 && choice != 2);

    printf ("Please enter amount of money:");
    scanf("%f",&in_c);

    if (choice == 1 )
        {
            out_c = in_c / ex_rate_into_vnd;
            printf ("Your amount of money: %.2f",out_c);
        }
    else
        {
           out_c = in_c * ex_rate_into_vnd;
           printf ("Your amount of money: %.0f",out_c);
        }
//! End of Exchanging

    printf ("\nWould you like to buy a beer (y/n) ?",buy);
    scanf("%c", &buy);

    if (buy == 'y')
        {
        if (out_c >= 7000)
            {
                out_c = out_c - 7000;
                printf("Transactions success !\n");
                printf("Your amount: %2.f",out_c);
            }
        }
    printf ("\nWhy Stop ?");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you add the argument to printf when asking for the input?

Comment: There are several posts which can answer your question . Check out my answer on a similar question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614761/calling-scanf-after-another-string-input-function-creates-phantom-input/17615082#17615082

Answer (score 2):

You have at least one `\n` between the latest float entry and the `char` you want to read. You need to get rid of that first.

See also [all answers in `getchar` after `scanf` category](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getchar)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
scanf("%c", &buy);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &buy);
//     ^space
```

Because the newline character is still in the input buffer after you enter a number and press ENTER in the second `scanf`.

Comment: That's not quite a good solution.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac I agree this is just a quick and dirty way to fix the problem, however, I don't think using `getchar` with `scanf` is any better. The better way is to avoid using `scanf` at all, and use `fgets` and `sscanf` instead.

Comment: Your tweak will also not work if the user inputs a space before the actual input. That's why it's worse. I agree with you that `fgets` + `sscanf` is the way to go everytime but just look at how many people use the `scanf` approach.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `scanf("%c", &buy);`

1.use space before %c

```
scanf(" %c",&buy); //space before %c  
       ^
```

this skips reading of  white space (including newlines).

2.or Use getchar(); before scanf("%c", &buy); statement

```
getchar(); //this hold the newline 
scanf("%c", &buy);
```

3.or use two times getchar();

```
getchar();
buy=getchar();     
//here getchar returns int , it would be better if you declare buy with integer type.
```

In GCC usage  of `fflush(stdin);` is discouaraged. please avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why you made 'choice' a float, not an int
Also, consider using a switch-case
that way, you won't have to do the whole do-while loop.
Also, in the line 
printf ("\nWould you like to buy a beer (y/n) ?",***buy***);
Why did u add that?
Here is what I would have done :

```
printf("Your choice?\n>");
scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice)
{
     case 1 :
    {
         out_c = in_c / ex_rate_into_vnd;
            printf ("Your amount of money: %.2f",out_c);


    }

     case 2:
    {

    out_c = in_c * ex_rate_into_vnd;
           printf ("Your amount of money: %.0f",out_c);

    }

    default :
    printf("\nThere has been an error\n"):
    reloadprogram();   /* Reloadprogram() is simply to make this go back to the asking thing :) */

}
```

}

EDIT: also, where it says `if( <somevariable> >= 7000)`, change 7000 to beer, so that way, if u change beer, you won't have to change this :)

Comment: also, I forgot the `break` after each case...

Answer (score 0):

Put a fflush(stdin) to clear the input before the last scanf

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not portable, and is undefined behavior according to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn't skip the third input data, it just scans the newline you press after the second input. To fix this, type `scanf("%*c%c", &buy);` instead of `scanf("%c", &buy);`. This little `%*c` scans and ignores the the character read from the input.

Answer (score -1):

you can remove the `buy` variable from the printf call, it's unneeded

```
printf ("\nWould you like to buy a beer (y/n) ?",buy);
```

And replace `char buy` by `char buy[2];` . because a sting is always terminated by `/0`.

You can also add a `memset (buy, 0, sizeof(buy))`, to be sure that memory is reset before you start to use it.

Comment: `buy` is not a string, it's a character. Null-termination doesn't apply. And the `memset` is not needed.